Can we please have $\LaTeX$ in tag excerpts and tag wikis?
It has been brought to my attention in a private correspondation that

Our tag wikis / tag excerpts don't support $\LaTeX$, that is you won't see the rendered result, but rather the $\LaTeX$ code instead. As an example, it would be very sensible to put the following into the entropy wiki:$$H = -\sum_i \log p(i)$$ and $$H_\infty = -\max_i \log p(i)$$
Other sites have support for $\LaTeX$ in their tags and tag-wikis. As an example see the "calculus" tag on Math.SE

So, I'd like to ask for us to have $\LaTeX$ enabled not only for the main and the meta site but also for the tags.

LaTeX (more precisely MathJax) does work in tag wikis. (Example: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tags/modular-arithmetic/info)
However, I do observe a bug that when I edit a tag wiki (I just tried with modular-arithmetic), the preview initially shows rendered math, but as soon as I make any change it switches to displaying the $…$ part literally. This doesn't happen when editing a question or answer: the math is re-rendered after each change in the text edit box. I'm using Chrome on Linux.
There is no formatting at all in excerpts. No markdown, no links, no MathJax.
